# How do I annotate a barplot made from 2 different arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, annotations, bar-chart

So here is my chart:

[image]

The chart was made with 2 different arrays:

```
[' A6' ' Q2' ' Q5' ' A5' ' A1' ' A4' ' Q3' ' A3']
[ 748  822  877  882 1347 1381 1417 1929]
```

The first one being an array of strings I believe. Now, I've looked up different solutions to annotate the bars and each of them I was able to find were with pandas dataframe plots.  Mine has numpy arrays... I don't know if that should make it more complex or not?

Anyways, here is the code I tried to get the annotations on my chart:

```
plt.figure()
plot = plt.bar(x, y)
for bar in plot.patches:
    plot.annotate(bar.get_height(),
                  (bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2,
                   bar.get_height()), ha='center', va='center',
                  size=15, xytext=(0, 8),
                  textcoords='offset points')
plt.xlabel("Car Model")
plt.ylabel("Car Frequency")
plt.title("Frequency of Most Popular Audi Cars")
plt.ylim(bottom=0)
plt.show()
```

This code gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blablabla", line 137, in <module>
    plot.annotate(bar.get_height(),
AttributeError: 'BarContainer' object has no attribute 'annotate'
```

So it seems as though my BarContainer or bars have no attribute annotate... to be frank even after looking it up I have no clue what it means.

Could anyone help with this?

Thanks and sorry if code is missing info, tried to make it complete.

Comment: Use `matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`. [Plot and Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbJuG.png) and [Adding value labels on a matplotlib bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to annotate by using `axes.pathces` instead of `plot.patches`.

```
x = [' A6' ,' Q2', ' Q5', ' A5', ' A1', ' A4', ' Q3', ' A3']
y = [ 748,  822,  877,  882 ,1347 ,1381 ,1417, 1929]
fig, ax =  plt.subplots(figsize = (10, 7))
ax.bar(x, y)
for bar in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(text = bar.get_height(),
                  xy = (bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2, bar.get_height()),
                  ha='center', 
                  va='center',
                  size=15,
                  xytext=(0, 8),
                  textcoords='offset points')
plt.xlabel("Car Model")
plt.ylabel("Car Frequency")
plt.title("Frequency of Most Popular Audi Cars")
plt.ylim(bottom=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

Comment: wow this actually worked thank you! What exactly is the difference between axes and plot?